# TypeError: Unable to infer the type of the field _jdf

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to create a spark dataframe I came across this error:

```
a = []
if num_i != 0:
  i = 0
  for i in range(num_i-1):
    j = 0
    for j in range(num_j-1):
      k = 0
      for k in range(num_k-1):
        a.append(json_df.select(json_df["c1"]["l1"]["cc"][i]["nm"].alias("cl_nm"), 
                           json_df["c1"]["l1"]["cc"][i]["perc"].alias("cl_perc"), 
                           json_df["c1"]["l1"]["cc"][i]["at"][j]["link1"].alias("cl_at_link1"), 
                           json_df["c1"]["l1"]["cc"][i]["at"][j]["link2"].alias("cl_at_link2"), 
                           json_df["c1"]["l1"]["cc"][i]["at"][j]["lg"].alias("cl_at_lg") , 
                           json_df["c1"]["l1"]["cc"][i]["at"][j]["nm"].alias("cl_at_nm"),
                           json_df["c1"]["l1"]["cc"][i]["at"][j]["perc"].alias("cl_at_perc"), 
                           json_df["c1"]["l1"]["cc"][i]["at"][j]["dapi"][k]["cp"].alias("cl_at_dapi_cp"), 
                           json_df["c1"]["l1"]["cc"][i]["at"][j]["dapi"][k]["nm"].alias("cl_at_dapi_nm"), 
                           json_df["c1"]["l1"]["cc"][i]["at"][j]["dapi"][k]["vl"].alias("cl_at_dapi_vl")))
        df_cart_rec = spark.createDataFrame(a)
```

[image]

All fields are of type string and can contain nulls. Can this be adjusted in any way? The crash happens when I'm converting to a spark dataframe

Comment: Please do not post images, but only code as plain text. Also, provide a small reproducible example (small starting data, desired output and your attempts, for instance) so that other users can help you better.

Comment: @RicS I included the code the output is a normalized table with these fields!